# In typescript a API use axios return Promise<Array> isn't compatible with AxiosResponse<any>, How to do?

Tags: typescript, promise, axios

```
export class TransService {
  async getBindList (): Promise<{}[]> {
    const result: Array<{}> = await trans.post('/url')
    return result
  }
}
```

Error Info:
    TS2322: Type 'AxiosResponse< a n y >' is not assignable to type '{}[]'

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho9Ql.png)